# Transferring google app to another account while app update is still prending

Tags: google-play, release

perhaps someone has more experience in this, I need to transfer google app to another developer's account, therefore I have done some recent updates to release and now these updates are processing/pending. Question is - if I will initiate app transfer while new app release is still in process to be published, will another (target) developer's account receive transfer with my latest updates or same processing/status? Thanks :)